# The first, fifth, and eighth terms of an arithmetic progression are the first, second, the third terms of a geometric progression ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

The first term is $8$ and the common difference is $d\neq0$. The first, fifth, and eighth terms of the progression are the first, second, and third terms, respectively, of a geometric progression whose common ratio is $r$.

- What are two equations connecting $d$ and $r,$ and how can we use this to show that $r=3/4$ and find the value of $d?$
- What is the sum to infinity of the geometric progression?
- How can we find the sum of the first eight terms of the arithmetic progression?

Comment: Hard to read, at least

Comment: Once you've looked at the posted hint for your previous question on this general topic, perhaps you can tell us what your thoughts are on this problem.

Comment: You should also show your own work, after you get the answer to the first you can solve the rest also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series starts with a, and increases with d, so you get the numbers to be

$a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,a+4d,a+5d,a+6d,a+7d$ as your 8 terms.

$a, a+4d, a+7d$ are your terms in your geometric one. The multiplication from the first two terms is $\frac{a+4d}{a} $ or $ 1 +\frac{4d}{a}$, and the second multiplications is $\frac{a+7d}{a+4d} $ or $ 1 +\frac{3d}{a+4d}$

For a geometric progression, the multiplication is always the same so $$  1 +\frac{4d}{a} =1 +\frac{3d}{a+4d}$$  $$  \frac{4d}{a} =\frac{3d}{a+4d}$$ $$  4d =\frac{3d*a}{a+4d}$$  $$  4da+ 16d^2 =3da$$  $$  da+ 16d^2 =0$$ $$  16d^2 =-da$$  $$  -16d =a$$

This means that we can rewrite those geometric progression ratios to

$$  1 +\frac{4d}{-16d} $$  $$  1 +-\frac{1}{4} = 3/4$$

Answer (score 2):

The first, fifth, and eight terms of the arithmetic progression are
$$
a, \quad a+4d, \quad a+7d.
$$
The first three terms of the geometric progression are
$$
a, \quad ar, \quad ar^2.
$$
So we have
\begin{align}
a+4d & = ar, \\
a+7d & = ar^2.
\end{align}
Subtracting $a$ from both sides of both equations and then doing some routine algebra, we get
\begin{align}
4d & = a(r-1), \\
7d & = a(r^2-1) = a(r-1)(r+1).
\end{align}
Dividing the two sides of the second equation respectively by the two sides of the first, we get
$$
\frac 7 4 = r+1,
$$
so $r=\dfrac 3 4$.  Hence $a+4d=3a/4$, and so $d=-a/16$.

Answer (score 0):

We can write the arithmetic progression as $8, 8+d, 8+2d,\ldots$ and the geometric progression as $a, ar, ar^2,\ldots$

We know that the "the first term, the fifth term, and the eighth term of the [arithmetic] progression are the first term, the second term and the third term, respectively, of a geometric progression".

The equations that follow from these facts are sufficient to determine the three variables.

You can then use the standard formulae to determine the [infinite sum of the geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) and the [partial sum of the arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) of the first $8$ terms.

Answer (score 0):

1. ### List item

A.P in the given problem is 8,8+d,8+2d...

And it is given that the 1st,5th and 8th terms of the A.P are equal to the

,2nd and 3rd terms of a G.P.

First step.

First term of A.P is equal to the first term of G.P.

So, t1=a1=8

Second step.

t5(fifth term of A.P)=a2(second term of G.P)

i.e ar=t+4d

a=t=8 So,

8r=8+4d

2r=2+d after dividing both sides by 4

This is the equation which is the relation between ratio and the common
 difference.

Let this be eq1.

Third step.

a3=t8 as per the given information

i.e ar.r=t+7d where a=t=8

So, 8r.r=8+7d

as r=2+d/2 as per the eq1

we get 8r.2+d/2=8+7d

i.e 8r+4dr=8+7d

8r-8=7d-4dr

8.d+2/2-8=7d-4dr

4d+8-8-7d=-4dr

-3d=-4dr after cancelling -d on both sides we get

3=4r

and finally r=3/4, so the common ratio is 3/4 in the G.P
By substituting this value in eq1 we get the value of d which is -1/2.

And by applying the formulae for sum to infinity of the G.P and sum of first 8terms of the A.P which are 16/3 and  9/2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020),  [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

WLOG let the 1st, 5th and 8th terms of the AP be $a-4d, a, a+3d$.

As these are also the 1st, 2nd and 3rd terms respectively of a GP, the common ratio of the GP is

$$r=\frac {\overbrace{\;\;\;a\;\;\;}^P}{\underbrace{a-4d}_R}=
\frac {\overbrace{a+3d}^{Q}}{\underbrace{\;\;\;a\;\;\;}_S}
=\color{red}{\frac {\overbrace{\;\;\;3\;\;\;}^{Q-P}}{\underbrace{\;\;\;4\;\;\;}_{S-R}}}$$
by using componendo and dividendo.